# Циклическое вращение списка на Haskell

Tags: список, списки, haskell

Нужно реализовать функцию, задающую циклическое вращение списка. При положительном значении целочисленного аргумента вращение должно осуществляться влево, при отрицательном - вправо.

```
Prelude> rotate 2 "abcdefghik"
"cdefghikab"
Prelude> rotate (-2) "abcdefghik" 
"ikabcdefgh"
```

Также нужно обеспечить работоспособность на бесконечных списках (для сценариев, когда это имеет смысл) и разумную эффективность при большом числе вращений небольшого списка:

```
Prelude> :set +s
Prelude> rotate 1234567890 [1..10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
```

Я сделал такое решение:

```
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate _ [] = []
rotate 0 xs = xs
rotate n xs = bs ++ as where (as, bs) = splitAt (n `mod` length xs) xs
```

Но оно к сожалению не эффективно:

```
Failed test #1. Run time error:
main: out of memory (requested 1048576 bytes)
```

Какое тут может быть эффективное решение?

Comment: Ваше решение приводит к вычислению всего списка из-за функции length. На бесконечных списках оно, увы, работать не будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
  rotate _ [] = []
  rotate _ xs@[x] = xs
  rotate 0 xs = xs
  rotate n xs'@(x:xs)
    | n > 0 = rotate (n-1) (xs ++ [x])
    | n < 0 = rotate (n+1) (last xs' : init xs')
```

Что касается бесконечных списков: отсутствует возможность проверки списка на бесконечный, поэтому бесконечный или нет список должно определяться самим программистом, соответственно функция вращения бесконечного списка сводится только к отбрасыванию левого элемента и переходу к следующему, т.е. отрицательного вращения быть не может, да и сама задача вращения бесконечного списка не является корректной, на мой взгляд.